# "Population has increased (up) to more than 10 million"

Tags: parts-of-speech, phrase-usage

If I write:

> Population has increased to more than 10 million

Is it right to use *to* here or should I use *up to more than 10 million*?

Or are both wrong? Should I make any other corrections?

Comment: *Population has increased to more than 10 million* -is correct. *...up to* does not look good to me.

Comment: *Population* would usually have a determiner: *the population, our population*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "*increased to more than 10 million*".

The use of *increase* implies the '*up*' in your other suggestion.  So "*up to more than...*" would be tautology.

Comment: True, although "up" could be used if the verb was changed, as in: _"Population is now up to 10 million."_

Answer (score 1):

"Up to" is usually used to express an upper limit. Like, "Increasing agricultural output may have caused a population increase of up to 10 million." That is, the increase may have been less, but it could have been as much as 10 million.

So you want to say just, "increased to more than 10 million". This is the new value. Presumably before this the population was less than 10 million.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [*surpassed*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surpass) ("to go beyond") - because population is clearly not a static quantity -

> The population has surpassed 10 million.